# Why does this very clearly defined (in callback to JSONLoader) object read as undefined?

Tags: javascript, callback, three.js

Why is this THREE.Mesh() object undefined when it is clearly defined in a THREE.JSONLoader()?
Here is my code...

```
1: var player;
2: var playerCallback = function(geo, mats){
3:     player = new THREE.Mesh(geo, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(mats));
4:     console.log("Loaded Model: " + 'resources/models/Player.js');
5: }
6: JSONLoader.load('resources/models/Player.js', playerCallback);
7: player.position.set(0, 20, 20);
8: player.physics = false;
9: scene.add(player);
```

The error I am getting is directed at line "*7*" as saying that player is undefined.
Before that "*Loaded Model: resources/models/Player.js*" is displayed just as It should be.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is executed before the playerCallback block is executed.

The JSONLoader loads the external file, but that takes time to happen. While it is waiting for that file to load it continues executing your script.

So while it is loading the external file it attempts to access an undefined variable (player). In order to make this work properly you need to ensure that your program only attempts to access the player global after it has been defined.

To fix your code, do this:

```
var player;
var playerCallback = function(geo, mats){
    player = new THREE.Mesh(geo, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(mats));
    console.log("Loaded Model: " + 'resources/models/Player.js');

    performPlayerActions();
}

JSONLoader.load('resources/models/Player.js', playerCallback);

function performPlayerActions() {
    player.position.set(0, 20, 20);
    player.physics = false;
    scene.add(player);
}
```

All I've done is move your player code into another function and then called that after we know for certain that the player has been defined (after the external file has been loaded).